# Creating table for Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: c

Thank you in advance. I appreciate any and all feedback. I am new to programming and i am working on an assignment that prints the Fibonacci Sequence based on how many numbers the user asks for. I have most of the code complete, but there is one remaining piece I am having difficulty with. I would like my output in a table format, but something is off with my code and I am not getting all of the data I would like in my output. In grey is my code, my output, and my desired output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int i, n;
int sequence = 1;
int a = 0, b = 1, c = 0;

printf("How many Fibonacci numbers would you like to print?: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf("\n n\t\t Fibonacci Numbers\n");

printf(" %d \t\t\t%d\n \t\t\t%d\n ", sequence, a, b);

for (i=0; i <= (n - 3); i++)
{
    c = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = c;
    sequence++;
    printf("\t\t\t%d\n ", c);
}
return 0;
}

Here is my output: 
How many Fibonacci numbers would you like to print?: 8

n        Fibonacci Numbers
1           0
            1
            1
            2
            3
            5
            8
            13

Here is my desired output: 
How many Fibonacci numbers would you like to print?: 8

 n       Fibonacci Numbers
 1          0
 2          1
 3          1
 4          2
 5          3
 6          5
 7          8
 8          13
```

Comment: Did you mean `printf("%d\t\t\t%d\n ", sequence, c);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not getting all of the data

- That's because you are not printing the `sequence` in `printf()` of the `for` loop.

  ```
  printf("\t\t\t%d\n ", c);
  ```
- and even before 2<sup>nd</sup> number before `for` loop

  ```
  printf(" %d \t\t\t%d\n \t\t\t%d\n ", sequence, a, b);
  ```

---

try making the below changes to your code :

```
printf(" %d \t\t\t%d\n %d\t\t\t%d\n ", sequence, a, sequence+1, b);

sequence++; //as you've printed 2 values already in above printf

for (i=0; i <= (n - 3); i++)
{
    c = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = c;
    printf("%d\t\t\t%d\n ",++sequence, c); 
 //or do sequence++ before printf as you did and just use sequence in printf
}
```

---

**sample input :** `5`

**sample output :**

```
How many Fibonacci numbers would you like to print?: 5 
 n       Fibonacci Numbers
 1          0
 2          1
 3          1
 4          2
 5          3
```

---

**Edit** : you can do it using functions this way... it's nearly the same thing :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fib(int n)
{
    int i,sequence=0,a=0,b=1,c=0;

    printf("\n n\t\t Fibonacci Numbers\n");

    printf(" %d \t\t\t%d\n %d\t\t\t%d\n ", sequence, a, sequence+1, b);

    sequence++;

    for (i=0; i <= (n - 2); i++)
    {
        c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
        printf("%d\t\t\t%d\n ",++sequence, c);
    }
}

int main()
{
int n;

printf("How many Fibonacci numbers would you like to print?: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
fib(n);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: @lopezgera92 glad you figured out :)... next try looking at every `printf()` satement closely when you have output problem

Comment: I have one more question if you don't mind. The assignment asks that I "include a function, fib(), that receives an input parameter from main() telling the function how many Fibonacci numbers to output". I am a bit confused on how to pass my input "n" from main() to fib(). How would I go about doing that? @CherubimAnand

Comment: I appreciate the help. Thank you! @CherubimAnand

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to print `sequence` in the for loop. Print `sequence` along with `c` in the for loop after giving proper number of `\t`!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @DeeJay

Answer (score 0):

This would work, also it is better to properly indentate your code:

```
int main() {
    int i, n;
    int sequence = 1;
    int a = 0, b = 1, c = 0;

    printf("How many Fibonacci numbers would you like to print?: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("\n n\t\tFibonacci Numbers\n");

    printf(" %d\t\t\t%d\n", sequence, a);
    printf(" %d\t\t\t%d\n", ++sequence, b); //   <- and you can use pre increment operator like this for your purpose

    for (i=0; i <= (n - 3); i++) {
        c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
        sequence++;
        printf(" %d\t\t\t%d\n",sequence, c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
How many Fibonacci numbers would you like to print?: 4

 n      Fibonacci Numbers
 1          0
 2          1
 3          1
 4          2
```